# How to make apt-get upgrade -y not interactive

Tags: bash, apt

I am trying to write a script to provision a new server. It is important that all the commands in the script do not require user interaction. I want to run the command: `apt-get upgrade -y`. I have noticed when I issue this command directly (ie. not in a script), a pop-up appears in my terminal:

[image]

Is there an option, or perhaps an alternative command that upgrades packages without needing this user interaction? I imagine if I put the command in a script the script would stop at this point and never resume.

I could also not see how to add an asterisk to a line which I presume indicates you want to restart that service. However, that is a different matter...

Comment: What OS is this? This is not the behavior I get on Ubuntu, Kali Linux, or Raspberry Pi OS. I never get a popup.

Comment: It is Ubuntu 22.04 Server. The command was issued from my Linux Mint local machine using SSH. So the photo is my local machine's screen.

Answer (score 4):

In your script, before calling any apt command, you could do the following:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

Note that the [answer from ahi324](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73095811/5607207) is usually better. While it would require more work / be exhaustive in which options to select, and maintain that configuration over time (rarely changes, still there could be new settings to add or old ones to rename).

The `noninteractive` would consistently skip all those questions.

Comment: @ahi324 Similar to my comments to ahi324: if you could provide any background / discussion / elaboration and also comment on the advisability of my approach to including apt-get along with a lot of other server configuration in a single script I would be very grateful.

Comment: We don't know much about your context. Your approach sounds as good as any, as long as you can maintain it over time. For something like this, we could probably have used Ansible or Puppet, which would both have installed your packages without prompting for anything, very similar to DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive. Another take on it could involve building your own package, with dependencies, splitting your script into pre/post install/uninstall (while not necessarily addressing the non-interactive issue).

Comment: That is interesting. I am a bit worried about getting into ever more complexity but maybe Ansible and Puppet actually simplify things. I like the idea of having a very clearly defined description of how my server was configured. Do those tools make things easier or just more convenient once you have understood how to use them? I am actually using AWS EC2 instances and I can see that AWS have various tools for this but I have not investigated them. At least with bash scripts I am writing bash which is something I need for other things so good to learn.

Comment: Puppet may be too much / makes more sense with larger setups, becomes relevant when combining/integrating several classes with one another (webapp X inherits from webserver, webserver depends on monitoring setting up probes, ...), kind-of object-oriented, relies on a central server ... Ansible might be easier to get started with, while Ansible code is kind of self-documenting, order of execution is predictible, ...And then again: shell scripts are fine too.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server. I'm using `apt full-upgrade` and I get prompted for eg. service restarts. Is there another way?

Comment: keep the DEBIAN_FRONTEND, and try adding `export NEEDRESTART_MODE=a`. And/or, maybe using `apt -yqq <your-command>`

Answer (score 3):

`apt-get -y upgrade`, `apt-get -y install [package]`, etc. automatically assumes "yes" to boolean yes/no prompts.  Unfortunately, when more complex options are presented (e.g., service selections) and/or when no defaults are available to select, `-y` doesn't ensure non-interactivity.

Check out `debconf-get-selections` and `debconf-set-selections` (in Debian, the `debconf-utils` package).  Typically, to automate selections for future headless/non-interactive installations, one can:

1. Select the desired options in an interactive session (one-time);
2. Run `debconf-get-selections` to get the correct represetation of the setting (e.g., `debconf-get-selections | grep "^$package"` to obtain the correct representation to feed back to `debconf-set-selections`: tab-delimited package, setting index, type, and setting); and,
3. Script the setting using `debconf-set-selections` (e.g., `echo 'wireshark-common wireshark-common/install-setuid boolean true' | debconf-set-selections`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was wondering if you could point me to any discussions / tutorials relating to this as it is somewhat over my head. I have checked out `man debconf-set-selections`.

Comment: More generally, do you think it is sensible to try to get `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` into a script with loads of other stuff like installing PHP, Apache configuring virtual hosts etc etc. I can certainly see advantages in terms of reproducibility and error elimination but perhaps it is a can of worms?